# VS2010 Extension - code definition window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsix

I am listening on TextViewCreated from `IWpfTextViewCreationListener` interface.

How can I use the `IWpfTextView` I get as a parameter to differentiate between textview belonging to the "code definition window" and the normal text editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic code to accomplish this.

```
static bool IsCodeDefWindow(
    IWpfTextView textView, 
    IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService editorAdaptersFactoryService, 
    IVsCodeDefView vsCodeDefView)
{
    var vsTextView = editorAdaptersFactoryService.GetViewAdapter(textView);
    if (vsTextView == null)
    {
        // Happens for unshimmed IWpfTextView instances
        return false;
    }

    int isCodeDef;
    return
        ErrorHandler.Succeeded(vsCodeDefView.IsCodeDefView(vsTextView, out isCodeDef)) &&
        isCodeDef != 0;
}
```

The `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService` is a MEF importable component so it's available via `[Import]` on your MEF container.

The `IVsCodeDefView` is an older Visual Studio service.  If you have an `IServiceProvider` it's available via `QueryService` (be sure to use `SVsServiceProvider` as the service type and `IVsServiceProvider` as the interface).